# Problema al forzar ssl en mi dominio con htaccess

Tags: laravel

este es mi archivo que tengo en Laravel 5

> Options -MultiViews

```
#redirect www to website root
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#force https 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

al entrar en mi dominio.com deberia de redirigirme a https://dominio.com lo hace pero me da un error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es el .htaccess que utilizo para forzar ssl en un proyecto Laravel (Aunque laravel no tiene nada que ver con redirecciones).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Gracias.. aunque tengo otro problema con mi servidor compartido